# Decode config to case class with pureconfig with default values

Tags: scala, pureconfig

Assuming I have the following config:

```
{
  “default-value”:5,
  “some-seq”: [
    {“some-other-value”:100},
    {“foo”:”bar”},
    {“some-other-value”:1500}
  ]
}
```

I want it to be decoded to case classes:

```
case class Config(defaultValue: Int, someSeq: Seq[SomeInteger])
case class SomeInteger(someOtherValue: Int)
```

So that it creates Config(5, Seq(SomeInteger(100), SomeInteger(5), SomeInteger(1500)))
(Second one is 5 since there is no some-other-value key in the second object of the list)
Is there a way to do so?

Comment: What kind of config is that? Doesn't look like HOCON

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add quotes around the variable names in config and trailing commas. Was writing really fast, now edited to look like a normal application.conf file. It is HOCON 

Comment: Sorry, fixed in description

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a type parameter to `SomeInteger` and `Config` to specify what the type of `someOtherValue` should be. Then you create a `ConfigReader[Config[Option[Int]]]` and use the `map` method to apply the default:

```scala
case class Config[A](defaultValue: Int, someSeq: Seq[SomeInteger[A]])
object Config {
  private def applyDefault(config: Config[Option[Int]]): Config[Int] =
    config.copy(
      someSeq = config.someSeq.map(i =>
        i.copy(
          someOtherValue = i.someOtherValue.getOrElse(config.defaultValue))))

  implicit val reader: ConfigReader[Config[Int]] =
    deriveReader[Config[Option[Int]]]
      .map(applyDefault)
}
case class SomeInteger[A](someOtherValue: A)
object SomeInteger {
  implicit val reader: ConfigReader[SomeInteger[Option[Int]]] =
    deriveReader[SomeInteger[Option[Int]]]
}
```

Unfortunately this means you need to write `Config[Int]` everywhere instead of just `Config`. But this can easily be fixed by renaming `Config` to e. g. `GenConfig` and add a type alias: `type Config = GenConfig[Int]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked!
I have a question - is there any more convenient way to do so? In my case, I have a bit more complex config, and only one field should be processed this way. Is there a way to introduce smth like custom reading for specific class?

Comment: Yes, there is a way to customize reading for a specific class: write a custom `ConfigReader` like above.
Regarding the “more complex config” thing, I don't see the problem. If you declare it like `case class MoreComplexConfig(config: GenConfig[Int])`, then things should just work. You don't need a type parameter for `MoreComplexConfig` – looks convenient to me.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was trying to write something like this for several hours, and finally gave up . Now everything works perfectly

Comment: In that case you may want to mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: Thanks, it was my first question on stackoverflow, didn't know how to mark as accepted 